# navigate table without using pairs in Lua

Tags: lua, lua-table

Hello im a newbie in Lua i just want to know if there is a way to get key and value of table **not using pairs,ipairs,next or other iterators**? thanks in advance.!

Comment: actually its my assignment creating a morse code..using pairs it can be done easily. but our teacher said if we try not using pairs or iterators he will            give us better grades. i was already stuck whole day searching a way to not use iterators but i still haven't found a way...

Comment: The primitive function for traversing tables is `next`. Without it, or `pairs` (which uses `next`), there is not other way.

Comment: yeah that is why im soo confused on how to traverse table without using the function built by lua... thank for the reply

Comment: If you build the table and no key is equal to a value, you can say `t[k], t[v] = v, k` (i.e. add bidirectional entries).  Then, if you can enumerate one of them externally (e.g. letters a,b,c…), you can also enumerate the other (here: morse code) because if you have the key sequence `k1,k2,…` you can get `v1,v2,…` by `t[k1], t[k2], …` and because you can do look-ups both ways, you can get `k` back from `t[v]`.

Comment: Am I losing my mind? I commented twice on this post yesterday "this makes no sense" and "is it an array? Or a dictionary?" But now they're gone...

Comment: i think i have seen it sir but dunno why its gone too.. btw sir my table looks like this ataEM = { ["a"] = ".-", ["b"] = "-..."} how can i access them get key or value without using pairs,next,ipairs or any iterators.. that's what my teacher wanted. my mind is already burned since im fairly new to Lua i mean like 3 days ehjeheh

Comment: Of course you can navigate if you know the keys and structure. Please show your code and explain why you don't know the keys. [edit] your question.

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe this is possible, as you've phrased your question in such a way that implies that the key is unknown. The only way to check for a certain value  and its corresponding key would be to iterate through the whole table.

However, maybe I misunderstood and you want to get a certain value from a key without iterating through the whole table.

Say you have a table named morse as follows:

```
morse = { a = ".-"; b = "-..."; } -- And so on
```

If you wanted to convert a single character to morse you could do as follows:

```
morse["a"] --Which will return the string ".-"
```

You can do the opposite, and define a table with all the morse values and their corresponding letters like below. Note the use of square brackets to 'escape' the characters.

```
morse = { [".-"] = "a"; ["-..."] = "b" }
morse[".-"] -- This will return "a"
```

Comment: sorry. i forgot to say i have to create a morse code that can convert english to morse or morse to english.  thanks sir for the reply i did try using that approach using pairs i can get both key and value, thats why i keep thinking how can i get the key like  'morse = { [".-"] = "a" }' morse = ["a"] would return "a" instead of ".-"

Answer (score 0):

Based on [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42147026/navigate-table-without-using-pairs-in-lua#comment71467232_42147876), I think you are looking for a string substitution using a mapping table. I think you can use [`string.gsub` here](https://eval.in/735023) (if your teacher still insists that `.gsub` is an iterator; you can ask them politely that you are unaware of the method they claim and would be delighted to actually learn about the same):

```
local str = "sos sos sos"
local morse = {s = "...", o = "---"}

print( str:gsub("%a", morse) )
```